# Clustering Data via Vectors and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-6.0

So given Enumerable of a class with some comparable properties (ints, strings, etc), can Linq perform a clustering algorithm easily?

So for example lets have the follow class:

```
 class Foo {
    string A { get; }
    string B { get; }
    string C { get; }
 }
```

The following would be considered one cluster because they all have at least one vector in common with one other member of the group:

```
{ "A", "1", "X" }
{ "A", "2", "Z" }
{ "B", "1", "Y" }
{ "C", "3", "X" }
{ "C", "100", "bar" }
```

If I have a cluster of Foos and a new foo, and I detect at least one intersection between one of its vectors and at least one from the cluster, it should be a part of that cluster too.

Also, if I have these two clusters:

```
{ "A", "1", "X" }
{ "A", "2", "Z" }

{ "F", "7", "Y" }
{ "F", "8", "G" }
```

The following Foo getting added to the system would apply to both clusters, causing them to now mutate together into one giant cluster:

```
{ "F", "1", "N" }
```

As string A `"F"` exists in cluster 2, and string B "1" exists in Cluster 1.

So what I'd like to do is have an IEnumerable and perform Linq operations to quickly group them into these clusters.

We have code right now that does the job but it is running in N^N time which is highly suboptimal.

Comment: Sorry, it's no clear what are you asking and your samples. Please show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I feel like I was pretty clear.

If you have classes A, B, they are considered part of the same cluster if at least one of their properties is the same.

If you add in C and it has an intersection with A or B, it also is part of that same cluster.

If you have class that doesnt intersect with any classes in any existing clusters, it is its own cluster now.

Comment: Steffen Blake and Steffen Cole Blake, are you the same person?

Comment: Yes. I didn't have access to my normal account at the time.